# Is it ok to ask whether a person is a descendants of a scientist?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

In particular, I would like to know whether [Anthony Bloch](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eabloch/) is a descendant of [Felix Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Bloch) or not. The [Anthony Bloch's page on The Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=33933) only shows his advisory relationships, not kinships.

I wonder if that's ok to ask? It isn't mentioned specifically in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me to be a borderline case, but I would say that yes, it is allowable, since an answer to that question is probably relevant to the biography of Antony Bloch.

Comment: What if the descendant isn't a scientist? What if the antecedent isn't a scientist?

Comment: @Ooker My answer was given in the context of a scientist and one of his or her antecedents. For instance, I would not think appropriate to ask here whether or not Olivia Newton-John is a descendant of Max Born (which she is).

Comment: So do you mean that the two persons in question must be scientists as well?

Comment: @Ooker No. Only the descendant.